# How do I get the iPhone SDK on Snow leopard?

Tags: xcode, iphone

I run MAC OSX 10.6.7 and have Xcode 3.2.6 and I do NOT have an [ADC](http://developer.apple.com) account.

My Xcode is missing Iphone SDK, from where and how can find/download it? and which SDK do you recommend, 3.0 ?

Comment: What do you mean Xcode is missing iphone sdk  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Get a developer account and download it from there](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action).   IIRC, the dev account is free and will get you an iOS SDK for the current shipping iOS version.  To run something on a device requires a $99/year fee.

iOS 4.x is the current shipping version.

Answer (score 1):

bbum is right that a developer account will allow you to download XCode for free.  However, you need to select an old version of XCode as the current version is for more recent operating systems (Mountain Lion at the time of this answer).

After logging in to your free Apple developer account, go to this link ([apple developer downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action)) and search through old versions of XCode.  The most recent that will work for Snow Leopard is XCode 3.2.6 with iOS SDK 4.3.

It's a very big file (over 4 GBytes!).  Good luck.